# If $f \colon K \to K$ is such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq |x-y|$ then $f$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a compact set and $f \colon K \to K$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq |x-y|$ for every $x,y \in K$. Show that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I am able to show that if $f$ is continuous then it is a homeomorphism. If you can show that the function is continuous I would be very happy =].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the inequality we know that $f$ is invertible and that $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz continuous. Take any closed set $A\subset K$, then it is compact because of compactness of $K$, and $f^{-1}(A)$ is then also compact, hence closed, so that $f$ is continuous. Hence $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, and so $f$ is a homeomorphism between $K$ and some subset of $K$.

Note: $f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(A\cap f(K))$, where $A\cap f(K)$ is compact, because $f(K)$ is closed.

Comment: To assure $f^{-1}(A)$ compact, it is not necessary $A \subset f(X)$?

Comment: @Oddone I think the solution should have said: "take any closed set $A \subseteq f(K)$".

Comment: @Jakobian Why is $f(K)$ closed?

Comment: @Oddone $f(K)$ is the preimage of a closed set $K$ with respect to $f^{-1}$, a continuous function, hence closed.